# How to proceed with wsdl in order to use external webservice?

Tags: wsdl

I have been given a wsdl . In order to use the web service , what and all do I need to do to complete that?
 I am new to web service task. THanks in advance !!

Comment: check this http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/consuming-external-webservice-in-apex/

Answer (score 1):

As with most things Salesforce these days, a good starting point would be the corresponding Trailhead module: [Apex Integration Services - Apex SOAP Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_soap_callouts). This will help guide you through using the built in WSDL2Apex tool to generate the Apex classes required to call out to the web service. There are more details in [Apex Web Services and Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#Apex_Callouts).

One important thing to remember is to add the Remote Site Settings in Salesforce so that the callout is allowed to occur.

If, for some reason, your WSDL has a feature that isn't supported by the native WSDL2Apex implementation you may need to work a bit harder to get it to work. Options include:

1. Modifying the WSDL by hand to remove the offending sections
2. Modifying the [open source version of Wsdl2Apex](https://github.com/forcedotcom/WSDL2Apex) to suit your needs
3. Using the alternative version of Wsdl2Apex the FuseIT gives out free (Disclaimer: This is a tool I make for my current employer). It won't solve all the possible WSDL problems that you will encounter, but it will help with the more common ones. See my Dreamforce 2014 talk - [Using the Tooling API to Generate Apex SOAP Web Service Clients](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s23U1cglPcI)